# Sentencias SQL en aplicacion .NET de Visual Studio

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Con la siguiente imagen pretendo explicarme de una mejor manera.

[image: Interfaz de usuario]
Mi objetivo es crear una App similar a Query browser. (No sé si será correcto decirle simulador de Interprete SQL).

1. Poder ejecutar sentencias SQL
2. Visualizar registros
3. Mostrar errores en las sentencias.

Pero al realizar la conexión debes definir a que base de datos deseas conectarte, lo que me impide mandar un “Create Database ”, únicamente puedo trabajar dentro de la base de datos, por eso agregue los combobox para cambiar de base de datos.

### Resumiendo: Como puedo ejecutar una sentencia de creación de base de datos desde un textbox.

Me pidieron mostrar el código que llevo hasta ahora así que acá se los dejo. 
Este lo tengo en un botón que agregue posteriormente aunque me gustaría que sea ejecute al presionar F5

```
    Dim sentencia As String
    sentencia = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox3.Text = sentencia

    Dim con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Conexion)
    Dim sql As String = sentencia
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)

    Try
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Tabla1")

        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tabla1")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        TextBox3.Text = ex.Message
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado mi estimado?

Comment: @fredyfx por ahora solamente he hecho la conexión, y ejecutar un select directo desde el datagridview,

Comment: edita tu pregunta agregando el código :D

Comment: @fredyfx ok esta bien, recuerdo que acá puedes crear con una herramienta de la pagina el código pero no se si seria de mas ayuda una imagen.

Comment: @fredyfx perdón por la tardanza, tenia ese código en otro proyecto por lo que lo pase a este con algunas modificaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Con este código puedes crear la BD, solamente concatena el nombre de la base de datos del cuadro de texto, para que sea paramétrico.

```
    Dim str As String

    Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=(local)\netsdk;" & _
                                                    "uid=sa;pwd=;database=master")

    str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " & _
          "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " & _
          " FILENAME = 'D:\MyFolder\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " & _
          " SIZE = 2MB, " & _
          " MAXSIZE = 10MB, " & _
          " FILEGROWTH = 10%) " & _
          " LOG ON " & _
          "(NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " & _
          " FILENAME = 'D:\MyFolder\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " & _
          " SIZE = 1MB, " & _
          " MAXSIZE = 5MB, " & _
          " FILEGROWTH = 10%) "

    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, myConn)

    Try
        myConn.Open()
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Database is created successfully", _
                        "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                         MessageBoxIcon.Information)
       Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
       Finally
           If (myConn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
               myConn.Close()
           End If
       End Try

End Sub
```

Por supuesto debes reviar el nombre de los archivos ldf y mdf de la BD

Con este ejemplo seguro lo haces.

Saludos